# setBackgroundColor() and setBackground() are mutually exclusive in android

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a circle of one color on a background of another.

```
background = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
background.getPaint().setColor(main.getResources().getColor(R.color.XXX));
view.SetBackground(background);
```

will work for the colored circle, and

```
view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.XXX));
```

will work for the background, but they're mutually exclusive. It just ends up with what I did last. Is there a way to make the circle on another overlapping view or something like that?

Comment: It's not something I've tried myself but have you looked at this guide to Canvas and Drawables? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setBackgroundColor()` is basically a short cut for changing the view's background to a colour drawable.

To do what you want you could try one of the 2 things described below:

1. Put a view in a **FrameLayout**, set the background colour in the **FrameLayout**, and put the shape in the view.
2. You could also try to use **ImageView**, which can have a background and another drawable with  `setImageDrawable()` method.

Comment: Using ImageView to draw a grid of white ovals on black backgrounds is instead giving horizontal black lines on a white background. I haven't tried FrameLayout yet.

I tried testing both of them on their own outside the grid I'm making. Each one crashed to program for no discernible reason even if I didn't modify it at all. Does it need to be created with a drawable or something?